# Extending a representation from the Weil group to the Galois group

Tags: galois-representations, langlands-conjectures

Let $F$ be a nonarchimedian local field. Since the Weil group $W_F$ is a dense subgroup of $G_F=Gal(\bar{F}/F)$, it's clear that restriction gives an injection $Irr(G_F)\rightarrow Irr(W_F)$ of irreducible (complex) representations.

In some notes of Prasad and Raghuram (found here: http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~dprasad/ictp2.pdf), they assert that the representations are in fact the same "perhaps after a twist." This fact is crucial for their argument that reduces establishing LLC for $GL_n$ to the case of supercuspidal representations. But I'm not sure I understand what it means.

So my question is: how does one take a representation of $W_F$ and twist it in such a way that it can be extended to a representation of $G_F$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick $V \in Irr(W_F)$. Due to Schur's lemma and the fact that inertia in $W_F$ acts through a finite quotient, some power of (a fixed choice of) Frobenius acts as a scalar on $V$. Take an appropriate root of that scalar to make up an unramified character $\chi$ of $W_F$ such that the same power of Frobenius acts trivially on $U := V \otimes \chi^{-1}$. I claim that $U \in Irr(G_F)$, i.e., that $W_F$ acts through a finite quotient on $U$. Indeed, that quotient is generated by a finite quotient of the inertia and the finite order image of the chosen Frobenius.

Comment: To elaborate: Let the $I_F$-action on $V$ factor through a finite quotient $G$. Then any lift $\varpi\in W_F$ of the Frobenius acts on $G$ by automorphisms, so some power $\varpi^N$ acts trivially on $G$. Now the original representation factors through $G\rtimes\langle\varpi\rangle$, and $\varpi^N$ is central, so it acts as a scalar on $V$.